# From to Create new Record and default in Values from Detail Object

Tags: lightning, form

We are looking to track changes made in our Customer Environments from the Case Object.
I have Created a custom object ChangeAudit__c with a Master-Detail relationship to the custom Object Change__C
On both of Objects I have created Picklist fields to track the Details

- ConfigurationImpact__c
- ApprovalRequired__c
- etc...

I would like to create a Form to create a new ChangeAudit__c record which after you select the Change__c this templates in the picklist values onto the corresponding fields on the ChangeAudit__c.

Is a Lightning Form the best way to implement this?
Would i need to use a Trigger or Process to populate the default values?

Comment: would not a screen flow work?

Comment: that worked - I was able to create a Screen Flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a Flow using the following Elements

1. **Screen** - Set the Change__c record
2. **Get Records** - Retrieve field values from select Change
3. **Create Records** - Create the ChangeAudit with values from Get Records
4. **Screen** - Run a custom Lightning Controller to automatically finish the Flow

[image]